# error = undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass> td-agent

Tags: fluentd, td-agent

I am trying to mask password using `@type record_transformer` some of my application log statement don't have message due to this am getting below Error from td-agent log file
is there any to over come this issue.
How to ignore this if message field not found.

```
2021-09-28 18:05:15.751529402 +0000 fluent.warn: {"error":"#<RuntimeError: failed to expand `record[\"message\"].gsub(/[Pp]assword*([^,]*)/,'******').gsub(/([Aa]uthorization\\s*.\\s*[Bb]earer\\s)[\\w\\.\\-^]+/,'******').gsub(/([Aa]uthorization_ml\\s*.\\s*[Bb]earer\\s)[\\w\\.\\-^]+/,'******')` : error = undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass>","location":"/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/plugin/filter_record_transformer.rb:310:in `rescue in expand'","
```

Answer (score 1):

The object which is having `#gsub` called (likely a String) is `nil`. Look for missing data getting to the record_transformer - maybe an incorrect Hash lookup returning `nil`?

You can guard on nil with the `#nil?` method on each object.

```
if obj.nil?
  # do thing
end
```

Comment: Thanks,  is there any example configuration?
Filter config
<filter log.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
   message ${record["message"].gsub(/[Pp]assword*([^,]*)/,'******').gsub(/([Aa]uthorization\s*.\s*[Bb]earer\s)[\w\.\-^]+/,'******').gsub(/([Aa]uthorization_ml\s*.\s*[Bb]earer\s)[\w\.\-^]+/,'******')}
  </record>
</filter>